# Validating information in a constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

How bad of practice is this? I am currently being asked by my professor to do this which is against everything I have been told. Can anybody give me examples why you should not validate this way? (Using regular expressions in the get / set methods in a asp web page)

More Information:

Here is the code of what he wants us to do:
In the Property:

```
public String FName
{
    get
    {
        return _fName;
    }
    set
    {
        if (validateName(value.ToString()))
            _fName = value;
    }
}
```

The method im calling:

```
public static bool validateName(String name)
    {
        bool isGood = true;

        Regex regex = new Regex("^[A-Z]");
        if (!regex.IsMatch(name))
            isGood = false;

        return isGood;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a sample please?  What is it that you are validating in the constructor?

Comment: Posted the edit. We are doing this with every property (there are roughly 15 consisting of name, email, state, etc.)

Comment: That's not the constructor. That's a property setter.

Answer (score 1):

In general it's not good, as *validating* as is, presumes also a *failure*.

So the questions are:

- How do you intend to handle faults during `constructor` code execution. ?
- What if you get an exception in `constructor`? What the state of the object remains after that ?

That's why it's a bad practice in general. The good path to follow is to:

1. Construct object
2. Run validation

But these are *guides*, and you're free to brake them based on your convenience. So in deffence of your professor, should say, that he asked this:

1. Or to bring you to some thoughts
2. Or to teach you something

So follow his path and try to understand why he asked to write the code in that way.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by validation, guard clauses are quite common practice in constructors e.g.

```
if(param1 == null) 
     throw new ArgumentNullException("param1");
```

It helps make sure that your object is in a consistent state for use later on (preventing you having to check at the time of use).

You can also use guard clauses on properties (what your case seems to be) and methods too, to ensure your object is always in a consistent state.

Answer (score 1):

In reply to your update, I'd find that really annoying, for example:

```
var a = new yourObject();
a.FirstName = 123;
```

What my code doesn't know is that I've failed validation so I haven't changed the first name property at all!

Edit:

Your can also simplify your validation method:

```
public static bool validateName(String name)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("^[A-Z]");
    return regex.IsMatch(name)
}
```

Comment: Ya and he didnt talk about that at all. I could set a boolean variable to whether or not everything validated and an array for those that didnt but seems like alot of work when there is an easier way.

Comment: You could make the property read only and expose a public method to set the value that returns a boolean indicating success. You should validate in the ui and when you save, I don't think that the object needs to validate as well.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your instructor.

In general, you should validate a value in any place it is possible to set it prior to "accepting" it. The general rule is that whatever method that attempts to set the value should receive immediate feedback when it attempts to set it.

For your example, I would place the validator inside of the setter of your FName public property, and if your constructor also accepts a FName value, then simply call the FName setter within your constructor to fully encapsulate the behavior of the property, be it validation behavior or any other business rules that the property implements:

```
public class User
{
    public User(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (!IsValid(value))
                // throw / handle appropriately
            else
                _firstName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Also: stay away from abbreviations! Do not use FName; use FirstName.

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of a constructor is to assign values to the members of a type. By convention, validation is not responsibility of constructor.
Validation of any information is dependent on business of the application that you are building. If you are creating a modular application where every component is meant for a specific purpose, it is better to create a separate class or a set of classes (depending on size of the application) to perform all business validations. Such validations have to be invoked depending upon the validation rules imposed on a piece of data.